# Adding 500 features dynamically to OpenLayers 4.6.5

Tags: javascript, openlayers, angular

I have a tile layer, three vector layers. I want to add 500 features dynamically to one of the vector layer using OpenLayers 4.6.5. It is currently working with 300 features and anything more than 300 features not showing none of the features in map. What might be the reason for this? Am I missing anything here?

```
initializeMap() {
    this.source = new OlVector({});
        this.clusterSource = new OlCluster({
          distance: this.distance,
          source: this.source
        })

        this.layer = new OlVectorLayer({
          style: (f, r) => this.styleFunction(f, r),
          source: this.clusterSource,
        });

        this.dockLayer = new OlVectorLayer({
          style: (f, r) => this.styleDockFunction(f, r),
          source: new OlVector({}),
        });

        this.countLayer = new OlVectorLayer({
          style: (f, r) => this.styleLabelFunction(f, r),
          source: new OlVector({})
        });





        let tileLayer = new OlTileLayer({
          source: new OlXYZ({
            crossOrigin: null,
            url: 'https://cartodb-basemaps-{a-c}.global.ssl.fastly.net/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          })
        });


        let view = new OlView({
          center: OlProj.fromLonLat([5.73271, 58.96564]),
          zoom: mapZoomLevel,
        });

        this.map = new OlMap({
          interactions: OlInteraction.defaults().extend([
            new PinchZoom()
          ]),
          layers: [tileLayer, this.layer, this.dockLayer, this.countLayer],
          view: view
        });
}
```

Features adding part follows.

```
updatePositionsOnMap(data: any[], isObservation: boolean, bike: any) {
    let points = [];
    let color = this.getBikeStatusColor(bike);

    let index = 0;
    for (let position of data) {
      let pointFeature = new OlFeature({
        geometry: new OlPoint(
          OlProj.transform(
            [position.Value.Longitude, position.Value.Latitude],
            "EPSG:4326",
            "EPSG:3857"
          )
        ),
        name: index == data.length - 1 ? bike.BikeId.toString() : "",
        data: this.getMapPoint(position.Value, bike.VisualId, bike.BikeId),
        type: "bike",
        session: bike.CurrentSessionId != null
      });
      points.push([position.Value.Longitude, position.Value.Latitude]);
      pointFeature.setId(bike.BikeId);
      this.source.addFeature(pointFeature);
      index++;
    }
}
```

Styling functions

```
styleCache: any = {};
  styleFunction(feature: OlFeature, resolution) {
    const childFeatures = feature.get("features");
    let session = feature.get("session");
    const size = childFeatures.length;
    let style;
    if (size > 1) {
      //style = this.styleCache[size];
      //if (!style) {
      let groupedBikes = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        let bikeObj = {};
        bikeObj["color"] = childFeatures[i].get("color");
        bikeObj["name"] = childFeatures[i].get("name");
        groupedBikes.push(bikeObj);
        // if (groupedBikes.length == 0) {
        //   groupedBikes.push(bikeObj);
        // }
        // else {
        //   let bikeDet = groupedBikes.filter(x => x.color == childFeatures[i].get('color'));
        //   if (bikeDet)
        //     groupedBikes.push(bikeObj);
        // }
      }
      if (groupedBikes.length > 1) {
        let bikeDet = groupedBikes.filter(x => x.color == BikeStatusColor.RED);
        if (bikeDet.length > 0)
          style = MapExtension.getClusterNumberStyle(BikeStatusColor.RED);
        else
          style = MapExtension.getClusterNumberStyle(groupedBikes[0]["color"]);
        style.getText().setText(groupedBikes.length.toString());
        //this.styleCache[size] = style;
      } else {
        let feature = groupedBikes[0];
        style = this.getLayerStyle(false, session, feature["color"]);
        style.getText().setText(resolution < 19 ? feature["name"] : "");
      }
      //}
    } else {
      let feature = childFeatures[0];
      style = this.getLayerStyle(false, session, feature.get("color"));
      style.getText().setText(resolution < 19 ? feature.get("name") : "");
    }
    return style;
  }

  styleDockFunction(feature: OlFeature, resolution) {
    let data = feature.get("data");
    //let color = MapExtension.getStationTickFeatureColor(data);
    let styles = MapExtension.getDockingStationsStyles(
      false,
      data.StationStatus
    );
    let text = "";
    // if (resolution < 19) {
    text = MapExtension.getFeatureName(feature);
    // };
    styles[1].getText().setText(text);
    return styles;
  }

  styleLabelFunction(feature: OlFeature, resolution) {
    let data = feature.get("data");

    let color = MapExtension.getStationFeatureColor(data);
    let styles = MapExtension.getTickStationsStyles(false, color);
    let text = "";
    if (resolution < 19) {
      text = MapExtension.getFeatureName(feature);
    }
    styles[1].getText().setText(text);
    return styles;
  }
```

How can I achieve loading 500 features without any issues particularly not affecting performance?

Comment: Poor performance can often be due to how the styling is implemented. Can you include the code for your style functions.

Comment: @Mike Please check my edited question.

Comment: Do `getClusterNumberStyle`, `getDockingStationsStyles` and `getTickStationsStyles` construct new styles each time they are called? If they do it would be much more efficient to maintain caches indexed by `StationStatus` and `color` similar to the commented out caching indexed by `size`.